# Why did Jewish kings wear crowns?

Tags: gentiles, clothing, malchut-royalty, samuel-shmuel-book-of

It appears that Jewish kings wore crowns. See for example [Shmuel Bet 1:10](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.1.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [12:30](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.12.30?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

The Torah does not instruct a king to wear a crown. Obviously the king can wear pretty much whatever he wants within reason but given that wearing a crown was a custom of non-Jewish kings and the lack of a mitzvah to wear one I would like to know if there was any particular religious reason that Jewish kings chose to wear a crown.

Comment: Keter is one of the sefirot...

Comment: @chachamNisan Nu, that's a literal crown?

Comment: @ezra Just pointing out that it's not a goyish thing.

Comment: @chacham can you source that that sefira was called keter before goyim used crowns for kings?

Comment: I rem an intresting Rashi on Divrei Hayamim about the crown of Dovid Hamelch

Comment: Kings wore crowns ceremonially.  Palace wall carvings, cylinder seals, all sorts of ancient items found show them. It's what they did--and it helped the folks in the back of the crowd figure out who was king.

Comment: @DoubleAA The sefira of keter was first mentioned in Sefer Yetzira which dates back to Adam harishon(about 5700 years ago) or Avraham Avinu(about 3300 years ago). The oldest known royal crown dates back around 620 years ago. There was a finding about 50 years ago in Israel of a crown-like object that historians claim is 6000 years old(I disagree; the world is only about 5779 years old) that's disputed to not be a crown, but a stand for an urn. See here; https://www.newyorker.com/culture/culture-desk/the-worlds-oldest-crown. And here; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_of_Princess_Blanche.

Comment: @Gary I thought that was what purple garments were for

Comment: @chacham it's not obvious they had the exact same text that we do, even if it had the same ideas. Plus some attribute it rather to r akiva, much later in history.

Comment: It's worth remembering there's an argument to be made that even having an earthly king at all(as opposed to Judges) was supposed to be a non-Jewish custom we adopted b'deveid

Comment: @postinganonymously - that was only later on, by Roman decree.  Before that, well, every set of tzitzit had a string of that color(murex-derived purple). It was expensive, but not limited to royalty.  A real live actual crown, however, was an element of the CoRO(W)Nations of all kings-and queens.

Comment: it just appears to be an ancient tradition - the guy in charge gets to wear the best hat.

Comment: I note that Rashi in Sanhedrin (21b, s.v. שבקש להולמו) says that the crown of the Davidic dynasty was unique, that it would only be able to rest on someone who was worthy of the kingship. שהיה שרביט של זהב בתוך חללה מדופן לדופן ואינה מתיישב בראשו אלא למי שיש לו חריץ בראשו, והיא עדות לבית דוד, שכל הראוי למלכות הולמתו, ומי שאינו ראוי למלכות אינו הולמתו

Comment: @DoubleAA see sefer malach raziel

Comment: There's nothing wrong with wearing crowns. It's the same idea that ppl wear black hats like goyim used too...

Comment: @TwoOs another work largely redacted in the middle ages

Comment: Or you can say that what difference does it make, all the Jewish kings were Kings and kings meet with kings so they needed to dress like the other kings

Comment: @DoubleAA perhaps even a farce, point being the idea of crowns existing before the world came about

Comment: Corona = Crown In Spanish, Crown = Keser. Folks, were almost at the top of Atzilus...

Comment: @Two that point is only valid if that book is from before the world came about, a highly debatable position

Comment: @double what makes a book? And it's called malach raziel who was before the world as we know it was created ...

Answer (score 2):

One could suggest that wearing a crown for a Jewish king is optional.

The Mishna in [Sanhedrin 22a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.22a.11?lang=bi&with=Steinsaltz&lang2=en) lists laws about a king's possessions that one may not use:

> מתני׳ אין רוכבין על סוסו ואין יושבין על כסאו ואין משתמשין בשרביטו ואין רואין אותו כשהוא מסתפר
>
> One may not ride on the king’s horse, and one may not sit on his throne, and one may not use his scepter, and one may not see him when he is having his hair cut,

Notice how "crown" is not mentioned in this list.

**However:**

The Rambam in [Hilchos Melachim 2:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.2.1?lang=bi) basically quotes this Mishnah verbatim **BUT** adds "crown" to the list!

> אֵין רוֹכְבִין עַל סוּסוֹ. וְאֵין יוֹשְׁבִין עַל כִּסְאוֹ. וְאֵין מִשְׁתַּמְּשִׁין בְּשַׁרְבִיטוֹ. **וְלֹא בְּכִתְרוֹ**. וְלֹא בְּאֶחָד מִכָּל כְּלֵי תַּשְׁמִישָׁיו.
>
> The king must receive great honor. He is to be venerated and feared by everyone, as it says, “Surely, shall you place” (Deut. 17:15) – that is, his awe is to be upon you. No one may ride his horse, sit on his chair, use his scepter **or his crown** or any of his serving vessels.

Here we see the Rambam adds "crown" to this list.

**Q: Why and how could the Rambam add to the list of items listed in the Mishna?**

**A: One could suggest that while a Jewish king may have a "crown," they're not obligated to wear it**.

---

**TL:DR** if wearing a crown was optional there must be no religious reason to wear one.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question, and I suspect you won't find a clear source. Even a surface reading of the *Tanach* makes it clear that there were many customs which the Jews either had from ancient times, or had adopted from their surroundings. The *Tanach* isn't a history book and doesn't detail things that don't have importance for all time.

Nonetheless, it's interesting to examine the various terms for "crown". The first you cited is נזר, which we see that Shaul wore. It appears in the context of the High Priest, who also wore a נזר הקודש - the golden *tzitz*, a metaphorical crown - on top of his hat. (And this may be why the rabbis refer to the [three crowns](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pirkei_Avot.4.13?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he): one of kingship, one of priesthood [see [Kiddushin 66a]](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kiddushin.66a.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), and one of Torah [possibly a reference to the crownlike border called the *zer* around the *aron*, ark, but also to the respect owed to a Torah scholar].)

The second source you cite is of the word עטרת. Here we only see this in the context of David taking it from the head of an Ammonite king and putting it on his own head, a clear sign of transferal of power.

The other Hebrew word for crown (common in modern Hebrew) is כתר. Interestingly, the only king who has this in *Tanach* is Ahasuerus in the book of Esther, but this word appears a lot in the Talmud.

Comment: I think this would make for a very useful comment but doesn't appear to be an answer to the question

Comment: I note that Rashi (Bereishis 50:10) alludes to the fact that ancient kings and princes wore crowns. When the Canaanite kings and Yishmaelite princes saw Yoseph's crown adorning Yaakov Avinu's coffin, they too, placed their crowns on Yaakov's coffin, and his entire coffin was surrounded with crowns.

Comment: With regards to the 3 diff wordings of crowns the Malbim in his sefer on words ,writes that an atarah is a crown that covers the whole head,a keser goes around the whole head ,and a nezer is only half the head (half of a keser).

Answer (score 0):

The Rambam ([Hil. Melachim 2:5](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=14&rtype=%25u05D8%25u05E2%25u05E7%25u05E1%25u05D8&hilchos=83&perek=2&halocha=5)) states about the king ומשים כתר בראשו, he places a crown on his head. So, contrary to the OP's assumption, it would appear that the Torah does instruct him to do so. (Now, it could be that the Rambam means it as an optional thing, but if so, why state it at all? A king presumably also has the option of choosing what color his royal robes will be, for example, but there's no need to codify that.)

In fact, the Rogatchover ([Tzofnas Paaneach on Bereishis 42:8](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=21163#p=247)) references in this connection a Gemara (Chagigah 16a) that says that anyone who gazes at a king (nassi), his eyes grow dim, and so suggests that this is precisely why he **should** wear a crown - so that they don't gaze at him. (Though I don't really understand that point - wouldn't that draw people's attention all the more? - unless he means that this way people will focus on the crown rather than on his face.)

Answer (score 0):

In the book of Zechariah 6:10-14 God instructs that crowns be made for the high priest and the ruler 'Tzemach'. Though this ruler is not officially a king (which would have been viewed as rebellion against the ruling Persian kingdom) most commentaries identify him with Zerubavel who descended from the family of King David amd may have had a quasi-kingly standing among the people.

Thus, though there may have not been a specific commandment for a king to wear a crown, it seems religiously appropriate.